# Would This Work?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

This is just a basic script for updating my database from form data.

I don't have much experience with databases and this might be a bad question but I have read online that you should use UPDATE because I've only ever inserted stuff to tables.

Any idea whats wrong here?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'main.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))

echo "You need to login to view this page";

else{

}
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$motto = $_POST['motto'];
$bio = $_POST['bio'];

if(empty($firstname) || empty($lastname) || empty($motto) || empty($bio)){

echo "You didn't fill out any fields.";

} else if (strlen($motto) < 5) {
echo "Your motto must be more than 5 characters.";
}

$sql="UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', bio='$bio',              motto='$motto' WHERE id='$id'"; 
?>
```

There are no errors that show up when its loaded because I fixed some of the other ones but obviously I didn't put for there to be text saying like "Update complete!" or whatever. But I wasn't sure if I should do and "else" around the $sql function. It looks like it should work in my eyes but it doesn't update them.

Database:
http://gyazo.com/b381e32d655f615b189e4fa46b74fa46.png

I do have it connected properly as I already have a register system, profile page, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query your update:

```
 mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

That is just an example. You can use PDO or MySQLi; whichever you have in place.

Comment: Thanks man! But where do the variables $connection and $sql come into? In my connect.php file I have no connect variable and its even showing an error saying sql and connection are undefined variables.

Comment: What does your connect.php look like? That will give me a better idea of how to help. You don't have to include your database info; just add DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  //connects to the server

mysql_select_db("users");  //selects the database

Comment: In that case use: mysql_query($sql);  right below your update statement.

Comment: Thankyou so much! You have helped me a lot. That would've taken me all day xD Thankyou

Comment: You are very welcome. Just know that the mysql_ functions are now deprecated in PHP. You'll want to consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php   http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: This is sorta off topic from my question but would you have an idea of what my varchar should be for Bio inside my database. I set it to 1024 randomly but I'm not sure.

Comment: That is acceptable; personally I always use 255 with varchar, but I never do a lot of storage with it. You can use up to 65,535 for varchar.

Comment: I don't really understand what Varchar is. I know its a variable character but I always thought it was what set the max length for the value of that structure.